# How to parse XML string with google script and output to new tab in google sheets as structured data?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, google-apps-script, google-workspace

Basically I am trying to do the following and need some guidance on how to do this.

I need to make this so the user can pass in a string in to a cell in Google Sheets, which is in XML format. A script will then take this string and parse into structured data and to a new tab in a new Google Sheets document. I do not know where to start and my programming/scripting knowledge is basic.

Many thanks for all your help.

Tried to do this in C# using LINQ but proved too advanced.

Update with code:

Thanks,

```
// Function takes user input string.
function buildUI() 
{
  // This creates the application itself.
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle("Please enter logic string");

  // Creates vertical panel
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();   

  // Create text box for dialogue.
  var text = app.createTextBox();
  text.setName('TextBox1');

  // Create submit button with label.
  var button = app.createButton('Click here to write to sheet');

  // Adds text box and button to panel.
  panel.add(text);
  panel.add(button);

  // Server handler for application to realise when user has clicked submit button.
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("submitButton");
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);


  // Adds panel to application. 
  app.add(panel);

  // Get active spreadsheet, call application.
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);

}

// Function for submit button
// Object e gets value of user submitted input.
function submitButton(e)
{
  // Gets application.
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
  // Get text box value based on user input string.
  var textValue = e.parameter.TextBox1;
  // Get active spreadsheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Write out to spreadsheet.
  sheet.appendRow([textValue]);
  // Closes after complete.
  return app.close();

}
```

Comment: Can you share your minimal, complete code?

Comment: Just submitted. Thankyou.